# Printing Arabic Text with Zebra ZQ 220 Plus Using CPCL on Android App

Tags: android

I have a Zebra ZQ 220 Plus printer, and I'm encountering an issue while trying to print a ticket in CPCL format containing Arabic text using an Android application. Unfortunately, the Arabic text appears as question marks (?????).

Thank you in advance for your help!

String cpclConfigLabel = "! 0 200 200 1000 1\r\n" + "ON-FEED IGNORE\r\n";

```
        cpclConfigLabel += "T ARIAL.CPF 0 150 100 TICKET DE VENTE\r\n";
        cpclConfigLabel += "T 7 0 460 150 "+dateSaleTxt.getText().toString()+"\r\n";
        //cpclConfigLabel += "ST SWIS721.CSF 06 07 20 200 Client :  "+clientTxt.getText().toString()+"\r\n";
        cpclConfigLabel += "T TIMES.CPF 0 20 200 Client :  "+clientTxt.getText().toString()+"\r\n";
        //cpclConfigLabel += "EXPANDED-GRAPHICS 10 6 20 200 " + Base64.encodeToString(imageByteArray, Base64.DEFAULT) + "\r\n" ;
        cpclConfigLabel += "T CAIRO.CPF 0 20 250 Vendeur :  "+agentTxt.getText().toString() + "\r\n";
        cpclConfigLabel += "T 7 1 10 280 _______________________________________________\r\n";
        cpclConfigLabel += "T 7 0 10 330 Produit\r\n";
        cpclConfigLabel += "T 7 0 200 330 Qte\r\n";
        cpclConfigLabel += "T 7 0 300 330 Prix U.\r\n";
        cpclConfigLabel += "T 7 0 500 330 Total \r\n";
```

configLabel = cpclConfigLabel.getBytes(StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1);

clientTxt.getText().toString() is an arabic text